# How can I get multi-scale features from pre-trained Darkent53?

Tags: computer-vision, yolo

Im trying to get multi-scale feature maps from pre-trained(ImageNet) Darknet53.
You know, Darknet53 returns output of softmax.
How can I get four different feature maps??

I tried to use Darknet53 from https://github.com/developer0hye/PyTorch-Darknet53/blob/master/model.py
But it returns only (num_classes) vector